# Suds client not working when passing as parameters but works with kwargs

Tags: python, suds

Sorry this might be a stupid question but im not too familiar with python.

On suds client if I pass arguments to the client method call using this:

```
kwargs = {'username': username, 'password': password, 'type': '', }

response = client.service.Login(**kwargs)
```

this works fine. But if I use:

```
response = client.service.Login({'username': username, 'password': password, 'type': '', })
```

This does not work, can someone please explain the difference and why it is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely you can see that in the first case you are unpacking the dictionary when passing it to the function arguments with the `**` operator (you are passing the key, value pairs as named arguments) while on the second case you are passing the function a single argument; the dictionary

```
{'username': username, 'password': password, 'type': '', }
```

If you do:

```
response = client.service.Login(**{'username': username, 'password': password, 'type': '', })
```

it should work

Comment: thanks so the ** allows the dictionary to be unpacked?

Comment: Precisely. You can do the same thing for lists (for unnamed arguments) with a single *.